# How to recover when a Route53 is missing from my Cloud Formation stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

This happened to me a couple of times now. A mistake caused the deletion of an entry in Route53, a CNAME in this case, from a Cloud Formation stack (driven by CDK). How do I cause the re-creation of this record? Re-deploying the stack doesn't seem to do it, as Cloud Formation consider it deployed.

I think this is essentially what's called drift?

Comment: Create it manually to match the entry in CF.

Answer (score 2):

Fixing this in CF takes two steps buddy.

1. Cut the CNAME resource from your CloudFormation stack and then apply it. This informs CloudFormation to delete that resource from the stack's managed resources.
2. Paste the CNAME resource again to the same CloudFormation stack and then apply it. This will force CloudFormation to both add it to its resource list and provision the Route53 CNAME.